# 3D acceleration is not enabled on Ubuntu 22.04 inside VMware 16

Tags: xorg, vmware, 22.04, mesa, 3d

Host: Windows 10 + VMware 16

Guest: Ubuntu 22.04

Problem: VMware 3D acceleration is not enabled

Does anyone hit the same problem?

How can I enable 3D acceleration on Ubuntu 22.04 inside VMware 16?

Detailed system info as below:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string:  4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.0.1

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no


glxinfo -B
name of display: localhost:10.0
display: localhost:10  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 22.0.1
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 3891MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 4.5
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.0.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.0.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20

lspci | grep VGA
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter

ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri
crocus_dri.so  i915_dri.so  kms_swrast_dri.so     r200_dri.so  radeon_dri.so    virtio_gpu_dri.so
d3d12_dri.so   i965_dri.so  nouveau_dri.so        r300_dri.so  radeonsi_dri.so  vmwgfx_dri.so
i830_dri.so    iris_dri.so  nouveau_vieux_dri.so  r600_dri.so  swrast_dri.so    zink_dri.so

lsmod | grep vmwgfx
vmwgfx                360448  5
ttm                    86016  1 vmwgfx
drm_kms_helper        307200  1 vmwgfx
drm                   606208  8 vmwgfx,drm_kms_helper,ttm

 modinfo vmwgfx
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/vmwgfx/vmwgfx.ko
version:        2.19.0.0
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Standalone drm driver for the VMware SVGA device
author:         VMware Inc. and others
srcversion:     9CD90269F5BEE0CDEA04828
alias:          pci:v000015ADd00000406sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015ADd00000405sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        drm,ttm,drm_kms_helper
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           vmwgfx
vermagic:       5.15.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        05:1B:11:1C:15:45:4E:B7:36:00:2A:E3:A2:EE:16:82:DC:31:C9:FF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      AF:27:A4:01:4B:E0:28:DB:DA:D6:A0:77:AC:4A:7F:79:A2:9C:0D:F9:
                87:4A:A3:88:8A:77:05:37:B9:57:A2:FE:48:4F:36:CB:FA:91:71:7E:
                FE:60:01:8A:18:B0:C3:60:62:4F:52:9B:D9:3C:B9:3B:2B:22:C3:00:
                FE:CD:20:99:2D:58:B7:36:61:13:8C:0C:92:5E:9F:AB:86:64:D2:90:
                96:3A:86:EC:67:A5:31:ED:1C:70:E1:0F:A6:9E:56:92:9B:9F:68:04:
                F5:82:5E:A1:8C:A3:3C:D6:E2:11:6E:84:33:57:CB:6B:AB:CF:93:88:
                B5:27:95:30:2E:12:FA:BE:09:97:35:A1:48:92:B1:88:D7:20:AC:7D:
                B3:10:F8:56:1D:29:47:99:59:88:4C:52:AB:46:7C:75:5B:E0:51:C5:
                01:E9:04:25:05:CF:AE:09:3B:B0:72:03:21:7C:18:FF:51:24:5E:BA:
                9D:BE:FA:EC:B2:6D:3E:A3:9B:77:86:97:49:2C:B9:DC:A7:60:E4:83:
                B8:D3:65:BA:08:66:40:80:5A:B6:FE:4E:8B:9C:52:D8:68:67:0A:CB:
                71:D1:32:E7:BB:53:05:07:0C:6E:9D:49:B0:70:64:F1:FB:CF:E5:38:
                08:CC:3C:8E:BF:0B:69:1F:6F:93:A9:ED:5A:9F:97:F0:19:B8:64:C7:
                90:9A:D3:D5:F5:46:CE:5E:30:71:B9:DF:EF:0A:E8:78:18:CF:FE:40:
                A3:3D:C9:AE:A3:10:4C:6B:88:B3:BD:F7:5E:02:AE:D3:EE:49:F4:C8:
                F4:0B:E1:B5:04:40:58:FE:D9:EC:BB:3D:89:B3:5A:44:5C:B0:B8:49:
                2C:A4:6C:0D:5F:F5:8F:99:77:67:09:B9:FD:2F:CD:FD:00:B9:3D:56:
                D8:BA:33:DE:E8:31:96:67:0E:0D:AF:8D:EF:BB:54:87:37:63:B7:F7:
                0B:BF:54:C2:2D:F2:12:1B:F4:E0:87:47:57:92:D6:D5:D7:3A:2D:2E:
                24:DC:1E:73:D6:49:A8:15:17:BE:5A:0A:71:F4:22:85:4C:4B:F7:3D:
                10:55:9D:87:54:73:03:F7:DA:CA:B7:FC:A6:1C:AC:1E:69:E4:C5:24:
                4B:82:09:23:C8:3F:AD:A7:91:E0:7A:4B:B7:AD:E5:B5:2F:1A:54:B5:
                0D:67:F3:3B:B1:13:DF:A7:77:88:4F:E9:59:D4:D0:8A:37:01:2E:C3:
                FA:22:C0:B2:94:3A:7D:ED:EF:BB:FC:7A:02:2F:C7:51:2B:B2:A8:E3:
                50:E7:BF:CF:06:DA:99:DE:98:3A:0C:7D:9F:41:5B:35:A9:1D:CB:F8:
                52:2A:7B:38:11:33:3D:9B:AF:B5:24:D7
parm:           enable_fbdev:Enable vmwgfx fbdev (int)
parm:           restrict_iommu:Try to limit IOMMU usage for TTM pages (int)
parm:           force_coherent:Force coherent TTM pages (int)
parm:           restrict_dma_mask:Restrict DMA mask to 44 bits with IOMMU (int)
parm:           assume_16bpp:Assume 16-bpp when filtering modes (int)
```

Comment: Install VMware tools.

Comment: I've installed packages "apt install open-vm-tools-desktop open-vm-tools" and start service "sudo service open-vm-tools start"
But glxinfo -B still show Device is "llvmpipe" instead of VMware SVGA